# Adding up values inside of a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, function, sum, while-loop

With the first query in the following code I am looking for the checkings made in Berlin under the game number two.

With the second query I want to give points for each of the checkings.

As you will see I am using the function SUM. But let's say that I have 2 checkings and the points for each checking are 50. Well, instead of echoing 100, with this code I echo 5050

What is wrong with it?

Thanks a lot

**THE CODE IS CORRECTED AND WORKING, JUST IN CASE SOMEBODY NEEDS IT. Thanks to all**

```
       $querya = "SELECT * FROM checkins where gamesid=2 and city='Berlin'";
 $resulta = mysql_query($querya) or die(mysql_error());

 $sumOfPoints = 0;
 while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($resulta)){

      $n = $rowa['venuesid'];
      $queryb = "SELECT venuesid, SUM(points) as sumpoints from venues where venuesid='".$n."' GROUP BY venuesid ORDER BY venuesid";
      $resultb = mysql_query($queryb) or die(mysql_error());

      while($rowb = mysql_fetch_array($resultb)){

           $sumOfPoints +=  $rowb['sumpoints'];

      }

 }


  echo "Total points is $sumOfPoints<br/>";
```

Comment: Why would it echo `100`? If you have two checkins, then the outer loop will always fire twice. If anything you _might_ expect `100100`.

Comment: this should be echo out of the while loop  or else it will keeps on loops, $rowb = mysql_fetch_array($resultb);
        echo $rowb['SUM(points)'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Some suggestions

1. Use `SUM(points) AS sum` (only for clarity when use the sum)
2. Check that points are numerical fields not varchar.

Answer (score 1):

points must be a string, you need to cast it

```
SUM(cast(points) as int)
```

and then follow Gaurav's point about labeling the compute

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `5050` because your script is echoing `50` in two iterations of the loop.

From the looks of it, your second query's `GROUP BY` clause is not grouping on `venuesid` when it should be. So, first try changing your GROUP BY clause to:

`GROUP BY venuesid`

If that doesn't give you the result you're looking for, then you should try running your query directly against the database with a static value for `venuesid` to see what you get back from it, then perhaps update your question and we can take it from there.